# NSPredicate for filter objects whoes string is BEGINSWITH special characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate, nscompoundpredicate

I have one scenario where I want to filter the objects of `NSArray` who have `NSDictionary` object and every object have key `name`. I want to filter with that number of objects whose `name` key value should be starting with special characters or numeric characters like `0-9,~!@#$%^&*()_` etc.

I have try to find this on google but not getting proper solution. I have used below predicate but not able to getting right objects.

```
NSPredicate *predicate=   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.name BEGINSWITH %@",@"[^0-9]+.*"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BEGINSWITH` operator doesn't support regular expressions. You can check if it begins with Non Alphabetic character using following in predicate:

```
 NSString *myRegex = @"[A-Za-z]*";
 NSPredicate *myTestPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF MATCHES %@)", myRegex]
```

Comment: not working.. it's crashing with exception on run time. `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "NOT (SELF MATCHES[c] '^[A-Za-z].*'"'`

Comment: I have tried after solving syntax error in predicate but still not working

Comment: Yes its working now, but I think `regex` should be this `@"^[A-Za-z]*"`.. but its ok its working.. Thanks once again.